# Predecessors and/or successors of numbers which are powers of $7$ are multiples of perfect squares?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let us consider numbers which are powers of $7$ like $7, 49, 343, 2401,\dots$ We observe that there is a pattern: numbers which are predecessors or successors (or both) of these numbers are multiples of perfect squares other than 1. Like, for example, consider 7.

Its successor is $8$. But $8=4\cdot 2$ and $4$ is a perfect square. Similarly, $49 = 7^2$, $48$ and $50$ are equal to $16\cdot 3$ and $25\cdot 2$, respectively. Similarly, for $343 =7^3$, $342$ is a multiple of $9$, and $344$ is a multiple of $4$.

Can we generalise this? Is there a proof to this pattern?

Warning: my math is rusty. (You must have got that from the question too... :-) )

Comment: I think it works for multiples of 5 too...

Comment: $7^4+1=2402=2*1201$ is not a multiple of a square.  Nor is $5^2+1$.  However, either $7^n+1$ or $7^n-1$ is a multiple of $8$, for every $n$.

Comment: @Michael I never meant that only successors of powers of 7 were multiples of square no.s. 2401-1 = 2400 = 100 * 4 * 6...

Comment: Counter Example: $6$, the predecessor of $7$, has factors $1, 2, 3, 6$. There are no factors of $6$ which is a perfect square (apart from $1$).

Comment: I have read your question again, I think what you mean is "predecessor or successor of $7^n$ has a perfect square $\gt 1$ as its factor". In this case, to avoid misunderstanding, better re-phrase the question as "the predecessor or successor (or both) of these numbers are multiples of perfect squares other than $1$."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

7 raised to any power is an odd number. 
Any odd number is neighboured by two even numbers, one of which is guaranteed to be divisible by 4.

Similarly, $7 = 1 (\mod 3)$, so $7^n = 1  (\mod 3)$, so we'd expect to see $7^n - 1$ being divisible by 9 about a third of the time. And indeed $7^3 - 1 = 342$ is a multiple of 9.

$7^2 = 49 = -1 (\mod 25)$, so $7^{4n} - 1$ and $7^{4n+2} +1$ are divisible by 25.

You can do the same for any prime square $p^2$ - find a low power of 7 (say $7^q$) which is a neighbour of a multiple of $p$, then $7^{pq}$ will be a neighbour of a multiple of $p^2$.

And yes, the same will happen for powers of any odd number.

Comment: What about 25? Like... Multiples of it? For example... 7^6 + 1 = 117650

Comment: Added a paragraph on 25 and a general method.

Answer (score 0):

$[x=7^n]\implies$

$[x\equiv1\pmod2]\implies$

$[x\equiv1\pmod4]\vee[x\equiv3\pmod4]\implies$

$[x-1\equiv0\pmod4]\vee[x+1\equiv0\pmod4]\implies$

$[4|x-1]\vee[4|x+1]$

---

Note that the same applies for every power of every odd number.

Comment: @Sandeep: What part is that?

Comment: ERM..x≡1.this??

Comment: @Sandeep: $x\equiv y\pmod n$ means that $x\bmod n=y\bmod n$.

Answer (score 0):

- When will $4$ divide $7^k+1$? Since $7$ has order $2$ mod $4$, only when $k$ is odd.
- When will $9$ divide $7^k+1$? Since $7$ has order $3$ mod $9$, and none of the powers of $7$ are $8$ mod $9$,this never happens.
- When will $25$ divide $7^k+1$? Since $7$ has order $4$ mod $25$, and $7^2\equiv-1$ mod $25$, this happens when $k=4n+2$.
- When will $121$ divide $7^k+1$? Since $7$ has order $110$ mod $121$, and $7^{55}\equiv-1$ mod $121$, this happens when $k=110n+55$.

We are seeing that the fraction "of the time" when $7^k+1$ has a square prime divisor is the limit of 
$$\begin{align}
a_1&=\frac12\\
a_2&=a_1+\left(1-a_1\right)\frac{1}{4}=\frac{5}{8}\\
a_3&=a_2+\left(1-a_2\right)\frac{1}{110}=\frac{553}{880}\\
\vdots&\phantom{{}={}}\vdots
\end{align}$$

---

A similar investigation for $7^k-1$:

- When will $4$ divide $7^k-1$? Since $7$ has order $2$ mod $4$, only when $k$ is even.
- When will $9$ divide $7^k-1$? Since $7$ has order $3$ mod $9$, when $k=3n$.
- When will $25$ divide $7^k-1$? Since $7$ has order $4$ mod $25$, when $k=4n$.
- When will $121$ divide $7^k-1$? Since $7$ has order $110$ mod $121$, when $k=110n$.

We are seeing that the fraction "of the time" when $7^k-1$ has a square prime divisor is the limit of 
$$\begin{align}
b_1&=\frac12\\
b_2&=b_1+\left(1-b_1\right)\frac{1}{3}=\frac{2}{3}\\
b_3&=b_2+\left(1-b_2\right)\frac{1}{4}=\frac{3}{4}\\
b_4&=b_3+\left(1-b_3\right)\frac{1}{110}=\frac{331}{440}\\
\vdots&\phantom{{}={}}\vdots
\end{align}$$

---

Averaging $A=\lim a_n$ and $B=\lim b_n$ gives the proportion of "the time" that $7^k\pm1$ has a square divisor. These calculations already show that it happens over $0.69$ of the time. But of course not all the time.

Answer (score 0):

As the remainder of $7/4$ is $3$, we can write $7 = 4m + 3$ for some positive integer $m$.

So $7^2 = 7 \times 7$ is $(4m + 3)\times 7 = 28m + 21 = 4 (7m + 5) + 1 = 4p + 1$ for some positive integer $p$. It follows that $7^2 - 1 = 4p$, meaning that the predecessor of $7^2$ is divisible by $4$.

And $7^3 = 7^2 \times 7 = (4p + 1) \times 7 = 28p + 7 = 4(7p + 1) + 3 = 4q + 3$ for some positive integer $q$. It follows that $7^3 + 1 = 4(q + 1)$, meaning that the successor of $7^3$ is divisible by $4$.

Applying the result for $7^3$, then $7^4 = 7^3 \times 7 = (4q + 3) \times 7$. Using the same argument in the second paragraph (replacing all $m$'s to $q$'s), $7^4 - 1$ is divisible by $4$.

So, indeed, you will find that when $n$ is even, $7^n-1$ is divisible by $4$. And when $n$ is odd, $7^n+1$ is divisible by $4$. Hence it is sufficient to conclude that the predecessor or successor of $7^n$ has a perfect square $4$ as its factor.